# Self join on two diff col of a same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a following table

### HQ1        HQ2

02400      02430
02430      02465
02430      02466
02465      02475
02466      02478

Here HQ1 is associated with HQ2 i.e 02400 is directly associated with 02430 and indirectly associated with 02430 02465 02466 02475 02478. How can i get all the association for 02400 in a single query? I have tried joining the same table but it doesn't give me all the associated values.

Comment: Can you please share the queries you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it using this query...

SELECT HQ2 FROM  START WITH HQ1='02400' CONNECT BY PRIOR HQ2=HQ1;

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Could be this  inner join

```
select a.*, b.* 
from my_table as a
inner join as b on a.HQ2 = b.HQ1
where a.HQ1= '02400';
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this help you, build the TREE

```
with a as (
         -- your data example
         select '02400' HQ1,'02430' HQ2 from dual union 
         select '02430', '02465' HQ2 from dual union 
         select '02430', '02466' HQ2 from dual union 
         select '02465', '02475' HQ2 from dual union 
         select '02466', '02478' HQ2 from dual

         -- another data example in same table
         union 
         select '02461', '02479' HQ2 from dual
         union 
         select '02479', '02478' HQ2 from dual
         union 
         select '02461', '0247X' HQ2 from dual
         )

select a.HQ2, level tree_level
  from a
 start with HQ1 = '02400' 
CONNECT BY PRIOR HQ2 = HQ1
```

you may select where HQ1 = '02461' to get other data.

Comment: Thanks, this helped.: